# Error inserting variable double in excel VBA

Tags: vb.net, vba, excel

i have a program that inserts in an excel file some value.
in the excel file it inserts the value of a variable(Double). The numberFormat of the cell is "€#,##0.00".It works pretty good when the value of the variable is 3.0 or 10.0 but if i put 3.5 or 10.3 excel throw an error like this:
[image]

In the first cell there is the right number but in the second it throw an error(number stored as text).
The code is this:

```
Dim price As Double
Dim price2 As Double
price = 5.0
price2 = 6.5
oSheet.Range("E1").Value = price
oSheet.Range("E2").Value = price2
oSheet.Range("E1").NumberFormat = "€#,##0.00"
oSheet.Range("E2").NumberFormat = "€#,##0.00"
```

Comment: try "€#,###.00" Both your examples are displaying incorrectly. 5.0 should be €5.00 not €5,00 Notice the comma in your example when it should be a decimal point.

Comment: @Fred I tryed it but it didn't work

Comment: Jeeped must be correct as it displays as expected for my regional settings.

Comment: @Fred well i tested it in a new visual basic project and it works but in my first project i put in a listview the variable (Double) then i put the text items of the listview in the cell but it does not work

Comment: Ok i solved! i added a variable just before insert the data of the listview in the cell

Answer (score 1):

You are running into system regional setting differences. Add a regional code to the number format.

```
Dim price As Double, price2 As Double, oSheet As Worksheet

Set oSheet = Worksheets("Sheet1")
price = 5
price2 = 6.5

With oSheet
    .Range("E1").Value = price
    .Range("E2").Value = price2
    .Range("E1").NumberFormat = "[$€-C07] #,##0.00"
    .Range("E2").NumberFormat = "[$€-C07] #,##0.00"
End With
```

Results should be similar to the following.

[image: regional_format]

Comment: If we want to be pedantic this does not match the OP's requirement as shown above.  This will put a space between the currency symbol and the first digit.

Comment: You're right of course. The space would first have to be selected and then the [Del] key tapped. Twice in fact. :)